# How to speed up SELECT query with 30 billion rows?

Tags: mysql

i have one experiment and try to find the fastest way to SELECT data from a table with 32 000 000 000 rows. Im open for any sugestions.
The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS htable (hbint bigint, offset double, other_id text)
ALTER TABLE "htable" ADD INDEX "idx_hbint" ("hbint")

mysql> explain htable;
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| hbint    | bigint | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| offset   | double | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| other_id | text   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The data inside looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT hbint, offset, other_id from htable limit 5;
+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
| hbint               | offset            | other_id                               |
+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
| 1873623171687526034 | 5.700362811791384 | 86269347961788316632308314800618355239 |
| 3987548381181600559 | 5.700362811791384 | 86269347961788316632308314800618355239 |
| 4522806684203010727 | 5.700362811791384 | 86269347961788316632308314800618355239 |
| 3300761751249036677 | 5.700362811791384 | 86269347961788316632308314800618355239 |
| -480229701304445181 | 5.700362811791384 | 86269347961788316632308314800618355239 |
+---------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

When I try to:

```
"SELECT hbint, offset, other_id from htable WHERE hbint IN (-5424874263835412947, 2382901849509990772, 1873623171687526034, ...)"
```

This takes forever. Around 5 - 15 minutes.

Hardware is 12 CPU/ 32RAM / 500GB Samsung 980 PRO, if it's matters.
I need help finding a way to speed up this query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your query references a `hash` column that doesn't exist in your table.

Comment: @WillemRenzema Yes, my bad, now is fixed.

Comment: How many hbint's are you looking up?  At least in MSSQL, that would translate to a lot of OR statements, which would be slow.  If you have a lot of hbint's to lookup, try putting them into a temp table, then doing an inner join on that temp table.

Comment: Is there are reason you don't have a `PRIMARY KEY` on your table?

Comment: I see you updated your Post and example query. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)  What is the average size of the `TEXT` column?  What is the max size of it?  Is any column "unique"?  How compressible is the Text column?

Comment: Thanks all. I will test all suggestions but will need time. @RickJames There is no PRIMARY KEY and unique column. Should I add? My idea was to keep the table as simple as possible.

Comment: @JonathanFite they can be 10 or 1000, is different.

Comment: If your `IN()` list is too long, MySQL's optimizer will give up and do a table-scan even though you have an index on `hbint`. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-optimization-memory-use for details.

Comment: "*There is no PRIMARY KEY and unique column. Should I add? My idea was to keep the table as simple as possible.*" - *Almost* every table should have a primary key defined.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an appropriate index on the table and re-writing the query to be more [sargable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) would probably help:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_htable ON htable (hbint)

SELECT hbint, offset, other_id 
FROM htable 
WHERE hbint = -5424874263835412947

UNION ALL

SELECT hbint, offset, other_id 
FROM htable 
WHERE hbint = 2382901849509990772

UNION ALL

SELECT hbint, offset, other_id 
FROM htable 
WHERE hbint = 1873623171687526034
...
```

Comment: Change to `UNION ALL` to make it faster.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks! I saw MySQL also has a `UNION` vs `UNION DISTINCT` clause. Wasn't sure what the difference was relative to SQL Server (which only has `UNION` and `UNION ALL`).

Comment: `DISTINCT` is the default and requires a temp table and sort.  `ALL`, _in newer versions_, tries to simply feed to results directly to the output (no temp, no sort).

Comment: Can you make a UNION of 1000+ queries in MySQL? I forget if there is a limit.

Comment: 5.7.3 (MariaDB 10.1.1) was when the UNION ALL optimizations were added.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many possible answers, here are some of the issues.

- 30B rows -- If the table continues to grow, that will be thousands of inserts per second; we need to discuss this.  `INSERT` is likely to be harder to optimize than `SELECT`.  [Deemed not a problem -- only 100 rows/day being inserted in the future.]
- If the `TEXT` can be compressed, shrinking the table size may be part of the optimization.  Compress in the client, write to a `BLOB`.  Typical text shrinks 3x; DNA sequences might shrink 5x.
- `IN(...)` -- Some versions will switch between doing (like J.D.) a union of many lookups versus a table scan, based on the number of values.  How many values in the `IN`?
- We *must* see all the rest of the queries.  Speeding up the one `SELECT` may hurt the other queries severely.  [Very few other queries.]
- If any combination of columns are "unique", then make them the `PRIMARY KEY`; this will nearly double this speed because of the "clustering".  Note: Adding a PK increases the disk footprint by only about 1% (assuming no other indexes exist).
- Some of my advice will depend on the size of the table, please provide a feel for that.  32G of RAM vs maybe 500GB of table?  That already says that "locality of reference" can be very important.  If you are inserting, what order do they come in?  [At 100/day, this is not an issue.]
- Only 500GB of disk?  You should keep half of that free in case you need to do an `ALTER`.  Either that `TEXT` is rather small, or you have not yet filled the table??
- Multi-threading -- Are the inserts/selects/etc coming through a single client, or multiple clients?  (This may lead to other optimizations.)
- `DOUBLE` takes 8 bytes; `FLOAT` takes 4 bytes.  Would it suffice to store only 7 significant digits and a narrower (but still generous) range?  That could save 120GB.
- When sizing the disk aware that InnoDB needs 2x-3x the apparent table size.  That is, the 190G in SQLite today may blow out the 500GB disk.
- You will have trouble converting from 180GB of SQLite to MySQL with only 500GB of disk.  I recommend at least 1TB to avoid costly stumbles.
- Having a `PRIMARY KEY` that *starts with* `hbint` would nearly double the speed of the query (relative to having a secondary `INDEX(hbint)`.  So, even if you add `id` as a PK, I recommend this trick:

  ```
    PRIMARY KEY(hbint, id),  -- to avoid a hop and use clustering
    INDEX(id)    -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
  ```
- Adding `id BIGINT` would add 8 bytes to each row (>240GB overall!) If you do not have a good candidate for a PK, then a 6-byte hidden PK will be provided.

To discuss disk footprint and speed, I will assume a baseline of 3 columns and *no* explicit PK or INDEX.  Then, the per-row size change will be at least

```
 +0 slowest (baseline - no indexes)
 +2 slowest PRIMARY KEY(id)  (id must be BIGINT to handle 32 billion rows)
+14 fast    INDEX(hbint)   (from your question)
+18 fast    PRIMARY KEY(id), INDEX(hbint)
 -2 fastest PRIMARY KEY(hbint, offset)  [if unique!]
+18 fastest PRIMARY KEY(hbint, id), INDEX(id)
```

Comment: Insert is not a big problem for now, because inserting once a day around 100 rows. And can be slower. Will try to compress the text. There is not much more queries. Insert and select. Will add a column with primary keys. The table is now SQLite 190GB. Cant be float.

Comment: How did you ever get to 30B rows at 100/day?  I added a comment on table size.

Comment: You are saying `DOUBLE` is required because `FLOAT` does not have sufficient precision?  Adding a new column `id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY` may be counter-productive.  Please elaborate.

Comment: (I change several bullet items.)

Comment: Huh?  190GB / 32B = 6 bytes per row?? How can SQLite do that?

Comment: @RadiPenchev - I added a bunch more.